# Cocos2D + Chipmunk: Disallowing Movement Along the X-axis & Preventing Rotation

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, chipmunk

## What I want...

The goal is to make an endless running game with obstacles and pitfalls that the player must avoid by jumping. In order to do that, the character cannot be allowed to move horizontally as the ground object(s) takes care of that. The only allowed movement would be in the y-axis (vertical) when the player jumps. Also in order to achieve this I need to negate any rotation that may occur with the body during game-play. Not sure if there's a way to do set some kind of dampener for rotation or what but that's why I'm asking.

## The questions:

- How do I cancel any movement/translation done to a body along the x-axis?
- How do I cancel any rotation done to a body?

*(Note: I haven't tried anything because I have no idea where to start and I'm new to the chipmunk scene)*

Comment: Set the body's position X coordinate after step to whatever value it should be. Also you may want to cancel linear velocity along the x axis. Same goes for rotation. Box2d actually has a flag to disallow rotation for bodies.

Answer (score 1):

Create the body with an infinite moment of inertia to make it non-rotateable.

As for making the environment move instead of the player, that's a little odd, but it will work fine. You have a few options, but they are all a little odd. You can set the surface velocity of the players shape to match the speed of the ground. Then friction forces will hold it in place until something hits it and pushes it backwards. When you clear the obstacle, friction will stop it's x-velocity again. If you set the surface velocity of the ground, then you wouldn't need to move it either, only the obstacles the player must clear.

It sort of sounds like you don't actually want physics though. Most runner games only need collision between simple AABBs which you could do much more easily with a couple dozen lines of code.

Comment: I asked a question about this same project before this one on whether I should use an API for physics or if there was a simpler way, I was told it would be easier to go with Chipmunk. Do you know of an example I can dissect and analyze for a non-physics version or would you care to explain this method in more detail?